# Why is only part of expression( ) displayed on my plot?

Tags: r, plot, expression, equation

```r
x = seq(0.1, 5, by=0.05)
y = x * log(x)
plot(x,y, col="darkblue", pch=".")
lines(x,x, col="darkred", pch="-")
points(y,x, col="darkgreen", pch=".")
legend("topleft",
       legend=c("y = f(x)", "y = x", expression(y = f^(-1) (x))),
       col = c("darkblue", "darkred", "darkgreen"),
       text.col = c("darkblue", "darkred", "darkgreen"),
       pch = rep("-",3))
```

[image: is]

I tried to add a legend to the plot of **f(x)** and its **inverse function**. The code and what it yields are the above, and what the legend **should** look like is the below. How can I make it right?

[image: should be]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a double-equals in the expression:

```
 expression(y == {f^{-1}} (x))
```

from `?plotmath`,

> ‘x == y’:                              x equals y

To prevent the `(x)` from being superscripted, you can use `{}` to group/protect the earlier part of the expression

Comment: Oh right, thanks! But somehow **(x)** is still written as superscript. Can you help me fix that as well?

Comment: Dank u wel!!! I tried to group them by parentheses...

Comment: by the way, you generally shouldn't edit your question to incorporate parts of the answer: that makes it more confusing for anyone who comes along later and wonders why the answers don't correspond to the questions ... (I took the liberty of rolling back your edit ...)  If you wanted to add "and how can I prevent (x) from being superscripted" that would be OK ...

Comment: You're right. I totally shouldn't have. Thank you so much!